# SVN basic questions

Tags: svn, version-control

1. When to use export, if the working copy is exported to another directory on client, does the 2 copies change simultaneously?
2. If switch the working copy to another dir on server repository, what's happening? Does it download the code from repository or upload the working copy to repository immediately?
3. How to use merge correctly? If I want to commit something to the repository and my working copy is not updated, should I use merge or update to update my working copy, then make my copy compiled and commit my edit to the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, they are considered to be two separate working copies.  (In fact, an export isn't really a "working copy" at all since it retains no bindings to the server as a checkout does.)  From the point of view of SVN, it's no different than if they were on two separate machines.  Updating one does not update the other, modifying one does not modify the other, etc.
2. I don't recommend using the "switch" functionality, even if you know what you're doing.  It's very easy to get tripped up and forget something.  But, to answer the question, it's basically replacing your local working copy with the target revision/directory on the server.  It should complain if you try to do this while your local copy has uncommitted changes, and you shouldn't do it in that case because those changes will be lost.  It's similar to deleting your entire local copy and binding to a new location on the server.
3. You should update the local copy before committing.  It's bad form to commit something based on an old version and have the merged commit contain errors.  Always make sure what you're committing (and where you're committing it) will compile and run and isn't broken.

Answer (score 0):

1) No. An export is a one-time action and cannot be updated like a checkout. Every export is independent. Checkouts are also independent - changes to one will not automatically affect any other. The changes are propagated only after running "update".